# C# how to unit test/verify that the APIs provided by a class are threadsafe?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, api, thread-safety

Do I need to put it under a multithread context? Or as long as the members of the class don't expose as shared resources and are immutable and readonly, that should proves it.

Comment: There is a tool called CHESS that can help find multi threading issues.

Answer (score 3):

Most instance methods in your api shouldn't be thread safe at all. Client code should decide -- depending on context -- whether to synchronize access or not, and at which granularity. Only static (class) methods would provide thread-safety and it shouldn't be mandatory.

To answer your question, I don't think there is a trivial non-context-dependent way for testing threading issues. Threading problems, such as data-races or deadlocks, are most of the time very hard-to-find: low probability, very dependent on input data, non deterministic etc.